# How to use if/else inside array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my following code:

```
$update = array(
                    'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
                    'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                    if($_POST['bday']){ -->THIS FROM SUBMIT FORM
                        'bday' => $this->input->post('birthday')
                    }
);
```

Is there is a way to do that if conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to append it in existing array like:

```
$update = array(
 'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
 'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
 'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
 'city' => $this->input->post('city')                   
);

if($_POST['bday']){ 
    $update['bday'] = $this->input->post('birthday');
}
```

**Check Live Demo:  [Click Here](https://eval.in/761638)**

Comment: array_push() will append value without key so its not useful in your case. Please use above code. It will append key and value both. @ReynaldHenryleo

Answer (score 1):

@Reynald Henryleo you can do it like below:

```
<?php
    $update = array(
                    'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
                    'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                    'bday' => !empty($_POST['bday']) ? $this->input->post('birthday') : null
            );

    // if you don't want bday with null value then try below one

    $update = array(
                    'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
                    'city' => $this->input->post('city')
            );
    if(!empty($_POST['bday'])){
        $update["bday"] = $this->input->post('birthday');
    }
```

Comment: hmm it will set 'null' as the value

Comment: yeah, don't you want null value ?

Comment: i want if conditional to add extra index 'bday'. So if $_POST['bday'] == FALSE then 'bday' index will not be set

Answer (score 0):

```
'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
'bday' => ($_POST['bday']) ? $this->input->post('birthday') : ''
```

[PHP docs reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: i mean it will declare 'bday' index